# How to align comments under its posts via PHP

Tags: php

I have two json records which I can successfully display its records separately.

Here is my issue. I want to append and display the comments of the second record based on the postid of the first record.

That is, I want to place all the comments under its post based on the postid.

```
<?php

// first record
$output ='
{"results":[
{"postid":101, "post":"my first post"},
{"postid":102, "post":"my second post"},
{"postid":103, "post":"my third post"}]
}
';


// second record
$output2 ='
{"results":[
{"postid":101,"comment":"my first comment"},
{"postid":102, "comment":"my second comment"},
{"postid":103,"comment":"my third comment"}
]
}
';


$json = json_decode($output, true);
foreach($json["results"] as $res){

            
echo $id = $res['postid'];
echo "<br><br>";

echo $post = $res['post'];
echo "<br><br>";
  
}




$json2 = json_decode($output2, true);
foreach($json2["results"] as $res1){

            
echo $id = $res1['postid'];
echo "<br><br>";

echo $comment = $res1['comment'];
echo "<br><br>";

  
}


?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add second `json_decode`, and inside loop take comments from that.

```
<?php

// first record
$output ='
{"results":[
{"postid":101, "post":"my first post"},
{"postid":102, "post":"my second post"},
{"postid":103, "post":"my third post"}]
}
';


// second record
$output2 ='
{"results":[
{"postid":101,"comment":"my first comment"},
{"postid":102, "comment":"my second comment"},
{"postid":103,"comment":"my third comment"}
]
}
';


$json = json_decode($output, true);
$json2 = json_decode($output2, true);

foreach($json["results"] as $key => $res){


echo $id = $res['postid'];
echo "<br><br>";

echo $post = $res['post'];
echo "<br><br>";
echo $json2['results'][$key]['comment'];
echo "<br><br>";

}
```

**Output**

```
101

my first post

my first comment

102

my second post

my second comment

103

my third post

my third comment
```

Comment: There is a chance for the array of comments to contain multiple entries for the same `postid`, in which case I believe this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through both arrays, find matching `postids`, and if they match add the `post` of the first array to the second array, at that key.

https://paiza.io/projects/-5zgfBWUs3jOJdNm0e1FZg

```
<?php

$output='{"results":[{"postid":101, "post":"my first post"},{"postid":102, "post":"my second post"},{"postid":103, "post":"my third post"}]}';
$output2='{"results":[{"postid":101,"comment":"my first comment"},{"postid":102, "comment":"my second comment"},{"postid":103,"comment":"my third comment"}]}';

$output = json_decode($output, true);
$output2 = json_decode($output2, true);

foreach($output["results"] as $val1){
    foreach($output2["results"] as $key2 => $val2){
        if($val1["postid"] == $val2["postid"]){
            $output2["results"][$key2]["post"] = $val1["post"];
        }    
    }
    
}

print_r($output2);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [postid] => 101
                    [comment] => my first comment
                    [post] => my first post
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [postid] => 102
                    [comment] => my second comment
                    [post] => my second post
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [postid] => 103
                    [comment] => my third comment
                    [post] => my third post
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, at each iteration where you print the post title and id, you will need to loop the entire comments records contained in `$output2` and if you find a matching `id`, then print the related comment. It is sub-optimal, but logically works like this:

```
<?php   
// first record
$posts ='{"results":[
                        {"postid":101, "post":"my first post"},
                        {"postid":102, "post":"my second post"},
                        {"postid":103, "post":"my third post"}]}';

// second record
$comments='{"results":[
                        {"postid":101,"comment":"my first comment"},
                        {"postid":102, "comment":"my second comment"},
                        {"postid":103,"comment":"my third comment"}]}';

// decode the posts
$json_posts = json_decode($posts, true);

// decode the comments
$json_comments = json_decode($comments, true);

// loop through the posts
foreach($json_posts["results"] as $post){
    
    // renamed variables to avoid naming clash
    echo $_id = $post['postid'], '<br><br>', "\n";
    echo $_post = $post['post'], '<br><br>', "\n";

    // loop through the comments
    foreach($json_comments ["results"] as $comment) {
        if ($comment["postid"] == $id) {
            echo $_comment = $comment["comment"], '<br><br>', "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, you should be able to retrieve posts and comments in a single data structure so as to avoid this double loop.

That is more so true, since - unless you specify otherwise - there might be more than one comment entries for the same post (which is normally the case), in which case you can't either break early out of the second loop.